# How to find the smallest number of several variables and return the column name

Tags: r, dataframe, min

I have some data like this

```
       A    B    C    D
[1,]  23   23   12   34
[2,]  12   13   11   9 
[3,]  70   80   67   76
[4,]  43   23   25   40
```

I would like to generate two new variable.

1. the smallest number of each row
2. the column name of the smallest value

i.e. the result should be like:

```
      A     B    C     D   min   minCol
1    23    23   12    34    12        C
2    12    13   11     9     9        D
3    70    80   67    76    67        C
4    43    23   25    40    23        B
```

I have tried the below script, and I did got the "min" variable, however, when I tried to generate the "minCol", some of the values were put down as "min", instead of A,B,C or D.

```
data <- transform(data, min=apply(data[,c(1:4)],1, min,na.rm = TRUE))
```

After I run this, I got the below data frame, which is fine.

```
      A     B    C     D   min   
1    23    23   12    34    12       
2    12    13   11     9     9        
3    70    80   67    76    67        
4    43    23   25    40    23
```

Then I run the below script

```
data <- data.frame(data, minCol= apply(data, 1, function(row)
        {colnames(data)[[which.min(row)]]}))
```

and got something like this

```
      A     B    C     D   min   minCol
1    23    23   12    34    12        C
2    12    13   11     9     9        D
3    70    80   67    76    67        C
4    43    23   25    40    23        min
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach would be (assuming your data called `df`)

```
df[c("min", "minCol")] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) c(min(x), names(x[which.min(x)]))))
df
#    A  B  C  D min minCol
# 1 23 23 12 34  12      C
# 2 12 13 11  9   9      D
# 3 70 80 67 76  67      C
# 4 43 23 25 40  23      B
```

Another approach (offered by @akrun) would be a combination of `pmin`, `do.call` and `max.col`

```
val <- do.call(pmin, c(df, na.rm = TRUE)) 
transform(df, min=val, minCol = names(df)[max.col(df == val, 'first')])
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(23L, 12L, 70L, 43L), B = c(23L, 13L, 80L, 
      23L), C = c(12L, 11L, 67L, 25L), D = c(34L, 9L, 76L, 40L)), .Names = c("A", 
      "B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
      "3", "4"))
```

Comment: Thank you. But when i use this script, R gives me a list rather than a data frame.  and if i run this script after i run my script, there are more value which are "min".

Comment: I've added the data set I've used. Isn't that what you have?

Comment: I've edit my question, the dataset I have at the beginning might have different format as you provided.

Comment: Ok, what does `cbind(data, t(apply(data, 1, function(x) c(min(x), names(x[which.min(x)])))))` gives you? Just note that if you have a `matrix` structure, you won't be able to have both `numeric` and `character` types columns at once, rather they all become `character`. I'll strongly advice to convert your data set to a `data.frame` using `data <- as.data.frame(data)` and then use the method provided in my original answer

Comment: I got the results after converting the data set to data.frame, and use the first method you provided. One more thing, I got "NA" in the data.frame, for those "NA", R either returns "min" or "minCol" in the "minCol" variable. Can it return "NA" instead?

Comment: That doesn't happen to me. I'm getting `NA` in the columns. You can also use `min(x, na.rm = T)` if you want to ignore `NA`s